# Opening Excel on two different monitors

Tags: microsoft-excel, display

Can I open separate spreadsheets on two different monitors? I have two separate spreadsheets that I'd like to look at on two different monitors.  How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3):

Typically, Microsoft Excel likes to open workbooks in a single Excel.exe process. The workbooks will appear as other tabs inside of one Excel process. To combat this, you need to open two instances of Excel, and open one document in each process. Then you can drag them along to whatever display you please.

Comment: I have helped a bunch of people at work by using the method Kaizerwolf recommends. I'll have them open the first workbook by opening the file directly (If it's on the desktop for example, just double click the file.) Then, go through the start menu to open another excel "session" and go through File>Open and navigate to the file.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You don't even have to do anything particularly special if you're using Excel 2013 or newer. Once you open one workbook, you can use the Open command to open the second workbook. That creates a new window, which you can drag to your second monitor.

If you want to view two different sheets of one workbook on two different monitors, that's a little tricky. (Excel tries to be helpful and won't open a new window with the workbook if you use the Open command again.)

1. Open the workbook as normal.
2. Open Resource Monitor (run `resmon`).
3. On the CPU tab, find `excel.exe`, right-click it, and choose *Suspend Process*.
4. Open a new instance of Excel. I had to right-click the taskbar item and click the *Excel 2013* entry, then right-click the taskbar item again before anything happened.
5. In the new instance, open your workbook. You'll be notified that it's in use, so choose to open it in read-only mode.
6. Use Resource Monitor's *Resume Process* command on the suspended Excel process.

You won't be able to edit the workbook from both windows at once, only from the one that originally opened it.

Answer (score 0):

When you have session of Excel opened, you can also hold down the Shift and then press your desktop Excel icon to open the second session of Excel.